# Tiny tiny rss monit

Tags: monitoring, rss-reader, monit

Help!
I want to set up a monitoring service on my Debian server, that will monitor and start wen needed the updater for tiny tiny rss. The problem is that it is a php foreground process normally run in a screen on a non-root user.

I can run it as:

```
php ./update_daemon2.php
```

or better putting it in the background and in order to run it from a different account

```
sudo -u tinyrssuser php ./update_deamon2.php -daemon > /dev/null & disown $!
```

I have installed monit, but cant seem to find a way to have it detect if t is running.
I would prefer to keep with monit but it is not necessary.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at:
http://510x.se/notes/posts/Install_Tiny_Tiny_RSS_on_Debian/

But use this instead under  /etc/init.d/
http://mylostnotes.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/tiny-tiny-rss-initd-script.html

make sure to set the user and group

Answer (score 0):

Create an upstart script `/etc/init/ttrss.conf`:

```
description "TT-RSS Feed Updater"
author "The Epyon Avenger <epyon_avenger on TT-RSS forums>"

env USER=www-data
env TTRSSDIR=/var/www/ttrss

start on started mysql
stop on stopping mysql

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/ttrss.pid --chdir $TTRSSDIR --chuid $USER --group $USER --exec /usr/bin/php ./update_daemon2.php >> /var/log/ttrss/ttrss. log 2>&1
```

Start the script:

```
sudo start --system ttrss
```

Add the following lines to your monit conf:

```
check process ttrss with pidfile /var/run/ttrss.pid
  start program = "/sbin/start ttrss"   
  stop program = "/sbin/stop ttrss"
```